# cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to *.exe.stackdump

Tags: c++, eclipse, stack-trace, eigen

I am getting "cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to TestProject.exe.stackdump" error. My project is nothing but a C++ HalloWorld project that contains an additional class in which I set and get a variable. I am getting this error at the line I try to set a matrix variable of type Eigen. Here is my code:

TestProject.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestClass.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    TestClass testClass;
    Eigen::MatrixXd XX = testClass.getVariable();
    cout << "X = " << XX;
    return 0;
}
```

TestClass.hpp:

```
#ifndef TESTCLASS_HPP_
#define TESTCLASS_HPP_
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>
#include <Eigen/Geometry>


class TestClass {
private:
    Eigen::MatrixXd X;

public:
    TestClass();
    void setVariable(Eigen::MatrixXd);
    Eigen::MatrixXd getVariable();
    virtual ~TestClass();
};


#endif /* TESTCLASS_HPP_ */
```

and finally the TestClass.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.hpp"

using namespace std;

TestClass::TestClass() {
    X << 0, 1, 2;

}

TestClass::~TestClass() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

void TestClass::setVariable(Eigen::MatrixXd x){
    X = x;
}
 /* namespace std */

Eigen::MatrixXd TestClass::getVariable(){
    return X;
}
```

The output I get in the Console is:

```
!!!Hello World!!!
      0 [main] TestProject 8416 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to TestProject.exe.stackdump
```

It is worth mentioning that when I change the type of the class variable X (and all related types in the methods and the header file) into an integer I don't get this error and the code compiles and runs.

I would appreciate any help since I didn't find useful info online.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a dynamic sized Matrix X, and you try to comma initialize it without setting its size first.  This will raise an exception:

As explained [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html):

> Eigen offers a comma initializer syntax which allows the user to
>   easily set all the coefficients of a matrix, vector or array. Simply
>   list the coefficients, starting at the top-left corner and moving from
>   left to right and from the top to the bottom. **The size of the object
>   needs to be specified beforehand**.

and [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ade5d2e09de50c2ca145037f295542b16):

> The coefficients must be provided in a row major order and exactly
>   match the size of the matrix. Otherwise an assertion is raised.

So resize your matrix first:

```
TestClass::TestClass() {
    X.resize (1,3); 
    X << 0, 1, 2;
}
```