# How to handle the error cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile

Tags: c++, c++11

can someone help me to find a fix my issue i'm facing. These quind of error seems to happen very often but everytime with other problems.

I think i have an issue regarding the size of the fstream object? 
Like in in this posted error with the matrix: [cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to *.exe.stackdump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676122/cygwin-exceptionopen-stackdumpfile-dumping-stack-trace-to-exe-stackdump)

```html
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include"ReaderWriter/WriterBuild.h"

using namespace std;

string path = "";
string file = "Testdatei.dat";
string message = "hallo";
bool status;

int main(){

//Testklasse erstellen
 cout << "start" << endl;
 WriterBuild Testwriter(&path, &file);
 status = Testwriter.write(&message);
 cout << status << endl;

 //cout << "End";

 return 0;

}
```

```html
#ifndef READERWRITER_WRITERBUILD_H_
#define READERWRITER_WRITERBUILD_H_
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace std {

class WriterBuild {
public:
 WriterBuild(string *ppathname, string *pfilename);
 virtual ~WriterBuild();
 bool write(string *pmessage);

private:
 fstream* _pfilestream;
 void checkPath(string *ppath);

};

} /* namespace std */

#endif /* READERWRITER_WRITERBUILD_H_ */
```

```html
#include "WriterBuild.h"

namespace std {

WriterBuild::WriterBuild(string *ppathname, string *pfilename) {
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
 const char* pfile = pfilename->c_str();
  fstream filestream;
  filestream.open(pfile, ios::out | ios::app);
  _pfilestream = &filestream;
  if (!_pfilestream->good()){
   cout << "Datei existiert nicht." << endl;
  }
  else{
   cout << "Datei existiert" << endl;
   }
  cout << _pfilestream << endl;
}

WriterBuild::~WriterBuild() {
 // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
 cout << "destructor-start" << endl;
 cout << _pfilestream << endl;
 _pfilestream->close();
 cout << "destructor-ende" << endl;
}

bool WriterBuild::write(string *pmessage){
 cout << "test pmessage: " << pmessage << endl;

 return true;
}

void WriterBuild::checkPath(string *ppath){


}

} /* namespace std */
```

Output:

```
enter codstart
Datei existiert
0xffffc940
test pmessage: 0x100407020
1
destructor-start
0xffffc940
105 [main] CMS_W_Engine 11556 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping     stack trace to CMS_W_Engine.exe.stackdumpe here
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor you have set the member variable `_pfilestream` as a pointer to the stack object `filestream`. Once the constructor exits the memory pointed to by `_pfilestream` is free for reuse (meaning other code is free to overwrite that memory). This means that your pointer `_pfilestream` is no longer a valid `fstream *` because the memory it is pointing to is no longer guaranteed to be a `fstream`.

If you want to keep `_pfilestream` as a member variable `fstream * _pfilestream` you should initialize it in the constructor using `_pfilestream = new fstream(pfile, ios::out | ios::app);` and then close and `delete` it in the destructor